# Search bar page retrieve info from database Parse

Tags: database, search, parse-platform

I would like to know how can I create a search bar on a sepearte view control that retrieve the information from the database i already have and fill in parse?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried)

Comment: I just found few tutorial but none of them had worked with me as I want to retrieve the information from the database not from a set table view that already filled with information. (I don't need something like when you search for the contact number in your phone) I am looking for something like when you search on twitter for example and its retive all the result from the database that has the same word that the user is trying to search for.